# What is the correct way of describing a standard brick pattern?

Tags: choix-de-mot

In English the standard brick pattern (where each brick lies half across the one below it - see below) is technically called "Running Bond" but might be described as "staggered" or "overlapping" by the layman.

How might I describe this in French (for example if I wanted tiles arranged like this)? I see the following translations for staggered: "échelonné", "étalé" and "décalé" and for overlapping: "superposé" but I am pretty sure that isn't right. Alternatively, a translation for saying "brick-pattern" might get the message across.

[image: Bricks]

Comment: I call that *rangées de briques **intercalées**". It's often used in archeology books for example to describe the way the bricks were piled up on Roman walls such as [these](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Musee-Cluny-frigidarium_02.JPG) (description [here in a book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=J-awHXTjDTYC&pg=PA527&dq=briques+intercal%C3%A9es&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNyduIloXmAhUkxoUKHVekAycQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=briques%20intercal%C3%A9es&f=false). There it is used in this description of the town of [Torino](http://www.italie-infos.fr/turin/torino1.htm).

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous why don't you post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Après quelques recherches il semble que beaucoup de sites emploient le terme "[en quinconce](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinconce)."

J'emploierais personnellement ce terme pour peu que les briques ne soient pas alignées, même si elles ne sont pas décalées exactement de la moitié de leur longueur, mais je serais sans-doute dans l'erreur car il semble que le terme désigne spécifiquement l'alignement tel que spécifié dans la question (les briques sont alignées une ligne sur 2)

Notons que l'une des pages liées dans la définition wikipédia renvoie vers [une formation de l'armée romaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactiques_de_l%27infanterie_romaine#Disposition_en_ligne_triple) où l'on parle effectivement de disposition en quinconce et le schéma correspond lui aussi.